# Why something connected to the ground has 0 potential?

Tags: electric-circuits, potential, voltage, conventions, earth

I'm studying the concept of grounding of neutral wire in AC. I have done an extensive research on the internet to answer the question "Why the neutral wire has 0 potential ?". The answer is because it is connected to the Earth. But I don't get it.

In general, why should something connected to Earth has 0 potential ? In fact, ultimately, I think that the hot wire can also be said connected to earth  indirectly via the neutral wire via the point B in the attached image, but may be it is not the case. And in the picture, I realize that the electric current can still flow from the neutral wire to the earth (following the orange arrow), so there should be a potential difference, right?

Could you please help me to clarify the mechanism behind it?

[image]

Comment: Ground isn't always neutral.  I once had a situation in which an electric motor was running with no power cable attached to the equipment.  There was a data cable connecting two "grounded" components separated by 100 meters.  There was enough potential difference between the locations to drive the motor.  I assumed it was because our site was hooked up to the commercial power grid.

Answer (score 4):

> I'm studying the concept of grounding of neutral wire in AC. I have
> done an extensive research on the internet to answer the question "Why
> the neutral wire has 0 potential ?". The answer is because it is
> connected to the Earth. But I don't get it.

It is more informative to say that the neutral wire is at the **same potential** as the Earth than to say it has zero potential. The designation of a point as having zero potential is purely arbitrary. Some point other than the Earth could just as well be assigned a potential of zero. Then the neutral and Earth would be at non-zero potential. But it doesn't matter. All that matters is the potential difference them.

The neutral conductor is conductively connected to Earth locally by way of the building grounding electrode, and more remotely by way of the one side of the utility grounding (earthing) electrode. See the Figure below. This makes the neutral conductor to the load at point B in the figure ***near*** earth ground potential.

I emphasized the word ***near*** because point B in the figure cannot be exactly at ground potential when load current is flowing. There will be a voltage drop in the neutral conductor between points B and F due primarily to the normal ohmic resistance in the neutral between points B and A whenever load current flows. That's because there is always some resistance in the neutral wire. But because the wire resistance in the neutral is much lower than the load resistance , the voltage drop between point B and the Earth would normally be very low.

> I'm a little bit stuck to understand why there is still the current
> flow from point B back to the source (120vac) when we say that all the
> points in the neutral wire are at the same potential as Earth (so no
> potential difference between them, so there should be no current
> between them). Can I clarify this a little bit ?

When there is no current flowing between point B and the Earth they are at the same potential. When load current flows between points B and A there is a drop in potential between point B and Earth due to the resistance in the neutral wire. But that potential difference is generally small, depending on the length of the conductor and the current.

For example, a US 15 ampere branch circuit uses 14 AWG copper wire. If you had 20 meters of that wire running between points B and A carrying the maximum possible load current of 15 amperes the potential difference is about 2.5 volts. This I why I say the potential potential is normally near that of Earth.

Of course, the longer the conductor, the greater the voltage drop. However, as I recall, the US National Electrical Code (NEC) requires that the maximum combined voltage drops on the feeder and branch circuits going to the furtherest outlet should be limited to 5%,  of the applied voltage, or about 6 vac for a 120 vac circuit.

One last point. Theoretically it is not necessary to have a potential difference in order for current to flow in a conductor, if the resistance of the conductor is zero. However, with the exception of superconductors, all real conductors have some resistance requiring voltage to generate current.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: Hi, could you please elaborate more on why neutral wire is at the same potential as Earth ? I know we can say that because it is connected to earth, but it is still unclear to me. Therefore I come back to my original question : Why something grounded has the same potential as earth ? Thanks!

Comment: @InTheSearchForKnowledge Simply because it is electrically connected to the Earth by a wire. Neglecting any wire resistance  points B, A, and Earth are at the same potential. t

Comment: Hi, I still don't get the idea. Sorry. But if i reason with the same logic, points B, A and the source are also connected by a wire, so why B, A and source aren't at the same potential ?

Comment: @InTheSearchForKnowledge Points B, A, and the neutral side of the source ARE at the same potential as Earth.  I'm sorry, but I fail to see what you are not understanding.

Comment: Hi, my bad, in fact I don't understand how the current flows. 1) in your figure, if we ignore the human, how does the current flow ? If i understand well, it flows in 2 paths: +) hot wire -> point A -> straight back to Utility power and +) hot wire -> point A -> down to earth -> inside earth -> up from earth to Utility power. Can you confirm it ?

Comment: and 2) if we add the human to the figure, I see that the current can flow : utility power -> point B -> via human body to earth -> inside earth -> up from earth to Utility power. I can't see why it is safe as you said. Can you please correct me ? Many thanks!!

Comment: @InTheSearchForKnowledge I'm working on a drawing to  replace yours to better reflect what's going on. Stand by.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the beautiful picture! However, i'm a little bit stuck to understand why there is still the current flow from point B back to the source (120vac) when we say that all the points in the neutral wire are at the same potential as Earth (so no potential difference between them, so there should be no current between them). Can I clarify this a little bit ? Many thanks!

Comment: @InTheSearchForKnowledge I have updated my answer to clarify. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hello, thank you! But I still don't get it (maybe i'm slow). From your answer, I understand that there is no current flow from point B to point A, down to earth (point F). However, I understand also that because the neutral wire is the return path of the circuit, there MUST be a current flow from point B to point A and back to the source (Utility Transformer in your picture). So the 2 things contradict each other, which confuses me a lot (like one way, there should be current, and another way, there shouldn't be any current). Can you please have a look again at my question above ? Many thanks!

Comment: @InTheSearchForKnowledge I’m saying IF there’s no current THEN there’s no potential difference between B and earth. On the other hand with no load current there IS a potential difference between the ungrounded (hot) conductor to earth. That’s the whole point. That’s the difference between the hot and neutrsl

Comment: Hi Bob, thank you very much for your help so far. I am still confused a little bit. From what you said above, can I understand that there is a current flowing from the hot wire down to earth (i.e. the current from Utility Transformer -> point B -> A -> D -> E -> F -> back to G -> F -> Utility Transformer) ?

Comment: @InTheSearchForKnowledge the current path for the load current is in red as that is the lowest resistance path. Some current may flow through ground but it would generally be small

Comment: Hello Bob, thank you very much! You are very nice! However, there is one thing with which i'm not comfortable. Yes, i know the path through earth has more resistence, but only from the point F (connection of the wire to earth), otherwise, the earthing wire (EF), like you said, has normally very very low resistence. With that reason, I think that there should be a huge current through it (because the current is huge at point B and it chooses the immediate path with lowest resistence which is the earthing wire, then it is blocked by the high resistence of earth). What do you think abt it plz ?

Comment: @InTheSearchForKnowledge One way or another all the current to the load has to return to the other side of the transformer to complete the circuit. It can go from B directly to the transformer through the neutral wire or by way of the path B-A-E-F-G. It can't just go to F and stop, as you seem to suggest.

Comment: Hi, yes, I mean it can go the way B A E F G, so in this case, there is current flow from the neutral wire down to earth, and because the current is huge in the neutral wire + resistence of the earthing wire EF is very small, i think there would be a huge current from neutral wire to earth, but it seems contradicts with what people say : there is no current from neutral wire to earth because there is no potential difference. Can you please tell me how to understand this contradiction ? Thanks Bob!

Answer (score 3):

The crucial point is:
The neutral wire is connected to earth by a *zero*-resistance
connection (the vertical blue wire in your drawing).
Then by [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law) the potential difference between the
neutral wire and earth is zero.

In contrast to this: The hot wire and earth are connected
by a higher resistance (the resistance of the load).

Comment: Hi, thanks!! I wonder if i remove the load, so there is no load between the hot wire and neutral wire, can we say that the potential difference between hot wire and neutral wire is 0 (because it is connected by a wire, without load) ? In this case, does it cause a contradiction given that we know for sure that the Voltage between hot wire and neutral wire is, say, 220V ? I'm a little bit confused. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hello, i have a question please. If I include a load in the blue vertical line, will there be any potential difference between the ground and neutral wire ? will there be any current from the neutral wire down to earth (and maybe, stay there) ? Thanks!!

Comment: @InTheSearchForKnowledge the answer to your first question depends on exactly what you mean by “remove the load”

Comment: @BobD: Hi, in this case I mean there is no load... (short circuit)

Comment: @InTheSearchForKnowledge A short circuit is not a "no load" condition. It is an "overload" condition!!!

Answer (score 0):

Grounding is incredibly simple at yet frustratingly complex.  You aren't the first person to find the topic difficult.

First off, as has been pointed out in other answers, voltage measures the *difference* in potential between two points.  At a pure physical world perspective, there's no concept of something being at 0V or 220V.  We can only say "There is 220V between the hot and neutral wires."  Of course, this is a really pesky way to analyze circuits, so we almost always make a little cheat.  We *define* a point, such as a point on the Earth, to be at 0V.  From that definition, we can then compute a voltage for any point/wire by finding the voltage between that one "ground" point and the other point, and adding 0V to it.

This point need not actually be a ground-as-in-dirt ground.  Whatever reference point you choose is your "ground."  And people are not obliged to agree about grounds.  You can calculate how a circuit behaves with a point on the Earth as ground, and I can calculate how the same circuit behaves with the hot wire as ground, and we will get compatible results.  One just has to be *really* careful to convert any absolute voltages correctly.

We define Earth as ground by convention.  If everybody uses the same convention, we don't get confused by absolute voltages.  This is particularly important when it comes to safety.  If two devices had metal containers at different potentials and they touched, current would flow between them.  This could cause a fire, or worse, an electrocution.  So the nearly universal agreement is that the Earth is ground, and such metal containers are required to be at 0V (we say those containers are "grounded").

We say "neutral is at 0V," but we say it a bit carelessly.  You're seeing the corners of where this carelessness matters.  So for this, we're going to have to start talking about real wires, rather than ideal wires.  Real wires have some resistance to them.  It's small, but it's real.

So we define the point where the blue wire drives into the Earth as "0V."  This is physically connected to the neural wire by a thin wire (typically inside your breaker box).  In theory there may be a little current going from neutral to ground (we'll talk about this effect in a bit), but its very small if present.  So we say that the point on the neutral wire that's connected to the earthing wire is also at 0V (or so close to 0V that we'll get away with ignoring it for now).

But go further down the wire, and this breaks down.  The neutral wire has a lot of current going through it.  And because the wire has a non-zero resistance, the voltage will be decidedly non-zero at the source or at any sink.  We can only say it's certainly 0V right where it is bonded to the ground.

And this is why many devices have a grounded plug.  A dedicated wire is used to provide continuity between that plug and the point defined as 0V.  By agreement, current is *not* passed down this wire.  By ensuring current does not pass down it, this provides a 0V wire to any component that's plugged in.  If one had a large load, one could indeed measure the difference between neutral and ground at that plug.

And that's how it should work.  You did ask about current flowing down from the neutral wire into ground.  And the answer to that is it's not supposed to.  You're not supposed to put any current into the ground.  But of course it does happen at some level.  We have a term for this: ground loop.   Ground loop is when current flows between two devices across the grounding wires.  This causes all sorts of problems, and you will indeed find that the simple models stop functioning here.  If you've ever heard a loud buzzing from a stereo, there's a good chance it was caused by a ground loop.

We have ways to minimize this.  In industrial settings, we have large copper grounding plates and wires to minimize the resistance of the wires on this grounding circuit.  We design systems to have a hierarchy of grounding wires to prevent loops from occurring.  And it all costs money.  For some situations, like residential settings, it's easier to just accept that the ground is imperfect, and it's not 0V at every point that is "grounded."